# making a video play continuously even when changing html page with javascript and without frames

Tags: javascript, video

I would like to have a video play continuouly even when html page changes.The new google videos page works this way. My page utilizes javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can only continue to play video if you are changing portions of the DOM, not if the location of the page changes.

Answer (score 3):

What about reloading parts of the page with AJAX.

Then you avoid a reload which would stop the video playing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to check into [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). This allows you to manipulate parts of the page (in general, the entire HTML DOM) using callbacks to the server via JavaScript. This is exactly what YouTube/Google Videos use to allow voting/feedback while still watching the video, since any page reload forces the browser to stop playback of the video and restart.

Depending on which web framework you are using, there are various different choices for AJAX libraries out there. Microsoft have create their own [ASP.NET AJAX]](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) for example, which is now very mature.

Comment: A in AJAX is asynchronous, not advanced.